# Photos: decrease in quality when exporting a live photo as a gif

Tags: macos, photos

The photos app decreases the quality of each frame to terrible levels when exporting a live image as a gif. Can somebody suggest a fix or an alternative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The GIF format was never designed to be for photos and by definition only allows 256 colours.
From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GIF), GIFs are used as follows:

> 1. GIFs are suitable for sharp-edged line art (such as logos) with a limited number of colors. This takes advantage of the format's
>      lossless compression, which favors flat areas of uniform color with
>      well defined edges.[23]
> 2. GIFs may be used to store low-color sprite data for games.[24]
> 3. GIFs can be used for small animations and low-resolution video clips.[24]

Comment: wow, didn't know that. Can you please suggest some alternatives to actually share the live gizmo on other social media platforms which is not actually a full fledged video but can be used as more of an image?

Comment: Sadly not, or at least not that I know of. Essentially it seems you do want a video.